# How to get scrollheight of CkEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to get `scrollHeight` of CKEditor in JavaScript but it returns `0` though it works fine in case of simple `textarea` object. Can you please tell me how can I get scroll height of CKEditor content in JavaScript?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use a framed editor:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstanceName.editable().$.scrollHeight;
>> 827
```

While `editable()` returns `<body>` element within editor's `<iframe>`, `$` will let you access the native DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

it will get content height, but not make sure whether if it's work for you, but try this surely it will help you

var currenId2k = "your div id";
var currentHeightPaste2k = $("#"+currenId2k).get(0).scrollHeight; //Content Height of DIV